# Cloudfront not following relative path within S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have an S3 bucket behind a Cloudfront which serves static sites with the following structure:

```
/s3-bucket
  /site-1
    index.html
    /assets
      index.css
      main.js
  /site-2
    index.html
    /assets
      index.css
      main.js
```

The `index.html` reference the JS/CSS like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index.css" />`

However, instead of using the relative path from the subdirectory, it uses the s3-bucket root and in the network tab I get an error with the files trying to be retrieved from `https://me.cloudfront.com/assets/index.css` instead of the desired `https://me.cloudfront.com/site-1/assets/index.css`.

So why is this happening and what do I need to do to get Cloudfront (I assume this is a Cloudfront problem) to honor the relative path of the S3 `site-1` or `site-2` subdirectories which is where the `index.html` files are being served from?

Comment: It's not a problem of CloudFront. Your browser is the one that translates relative urls to the absolute ones.

Comment: it could be due to your behaviour  config for the origin, can you share your behaviour config ?